# D3 code not responsive after page refresh

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Pretty new to this but can't figure out what must be the simplest of fixes? When I open the page in safari (running a local server through terminal) everything seems to work fine. However, when I refresh the page the SVG is drawn but the D3 interactivity doesn't work. If I wait for maybe 45 seconds and refresh again, it works.

I have a simple index.html which loads an SVG file made using Illustrator. I also reference a very basic js script with some d3 code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> test site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"       >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v5.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>
    d3.xml('floor.svg')
         .then(data => {
               d3.select('body').node().append(data.documentElement)
         })
</script>


<script src="myScript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

myScript.js

```
d3.selectAll("rect")
    .on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "blue");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "white")
    });
```

Comment: might be issue with safari; it causes more headache to me than even internet explorer

Comment: Thanks - actually just noticed that it doesn't work at all in chrome / firefox. Tried moving my svg inline instead and seems to work fine in everything. Just seems a pain to use inline as it's a massive SVG file :(